# Marketing Cloud : Row Fields from data extension into a single email

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Some background - we have list of job vacancies that needs to go out as a part of Newsletter every fortnight.

Through SQL - I was able to pull all the live vacancies from service cloud in a single data extension. Now the challenge I face is: I want the data to populate in below format(See picture) in a single email. The vacancies in data extension are **in a row** and I dont see a way to add each row to below vacancy card. Any ideas on how to achieve this please. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you include some sample data in the data extension and the desired output?

Comment: Use a FOR loop with a counter... "FOR @i = 1 TO ROWCOUNT(@myrecordset) DO" then use modulus (MOD(@i,2)) to figure out odd and even row numbers to use a ContentBlockByKey("vacancycard_odd") or ContentBlockByKey("vacancycard_even") to pull in the correct card populated with variables from your @myrecordset row.

Comment: Thank you Macca. Is your solution referring to Amp Script? Do I build AMP script to get row data of data extension into an email?